# Are Tails related questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is a proposed by the Tor Project way to use Tor. Are Tails related questions on topic for tor.stackexchange.com or not ?

Answer (score 8):

I would say yes here. As you said [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is an official [project](https://www.torproject.org/projects/projects) in the Tor universe and according to the [definition at Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56447?phase=definition) Tor.SE is for researchers, developers and users of Tor. I consider every official Tor subproject as part of Tor.

Comment: I agree completely.